# How does one map the client_version value (from sys.dm_exec_sessions) to TDS Version?

Tags: sql-server, dm-exec-sessions, tabular-data-stream

From Microsoft's SQL Server documentation of [sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql)

```
client_interface_name
Name of library/driver being used by the client to communicate with the server.
datatype: nvarchar(32)

client_version
TDS protocol version of the interface that is used by the client to connect to the server.
datatype: int
```

From Microsoft's TDS (Tabular Data Stream) Protocol [message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/773a62b6-ee89-4c02-9e5e-344882630aac#Appendix_A_Target_17) and [product behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/135d0ebe-5c4c-4a94-99bf-1811eccb9f4a#Appendix_A_17) documentation

```
TDSVersion
The highest TDS version being used by the client.
The client sends a standard LOGIN7 message to the server to discover the server's highest TDS version.
datatype: binary
```

Ben Gribaudo [posted a partial value map](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/14) and suggests that client_version is, in fact, not the actual TDS Version.

Questions
(1) What is the client_version value for?
(2) If the client_version definition (above) is correct, then where is the official documented map of integer values to TDS description (either string or binary values)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (1) What is the client_version value for?

For administrators it makes sense to go look for older libraries being used, for the server it is imperative to know this so that the correct protocol version can be used.

> (2) If the client_version definition (above) is correct, then where is the official documented map of integer values to TDS description (either string or binary values)?

It is correct for everything newer-ish (that's being nice). If you want to be complete it's missing 2 values:

```
0: TDS 4.2
1: TDS 6.0
```

There's no official documentation for this AFAIK.